# Using Nautilus in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, nautilus

How can I use Nautilus in Kubuntu?  When I try to summon it, it has a problem with gtk-bookmarks.  I  want to try it because Dolphin does not seem to recognize USB media.

> (org.gnome.Nautilus:46043):  WARNING : 10:47:18.250: Unable to get
> contents of the bookmarks file:
> Error opening file /home/paul/.gtk-bookmarks:  No such file or directory

Comment: `When I try to summon it, it has a problem with gtk-bookmarks.` -- What is the issue exactly?

Comment: See  updated description

Comment: It is only a warning. It should not prevent you from running nautilus in a different desktop environment.